# ParametricNDSolve doesn't correctly parse black-box function involving both independent variable and parameter

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration

Consider this toy example:

```
f[t_?NumericQ, a_?NumericQ] := t + a

tst = ParametricNDSolveValue[{x'[t] == f[t, a], x[0] == 0}, x, {t, 0, 1}, {a}]
```

> ParametricNDSolveValue::pdvar: Dependent variables `{x, f[t, a]}` cannot depend on parameters `{a}`.

As we can see, `f` is just a black-box function involving both independent variable `t` and parameter `a`, but `ParametricNDSolveValue`/`ParametricNDSolveValue` has mistakenly parsed it as dependent variable, spit out `pdvar` warning and failed.

I'm not sure if this should be considered a bug or design mistake. To make this post a question, let me ask: how can I circumvent the issue?

Answer (score 3):

I manage to find two work-arounds.

One is to set the `DependentVariables` option:

```
f[t_?NumericQ, a_?NumericQ] := t + a

tstfix = ParametricNDSolveValue[{x'[t] == f[t, a], x[0] == 0}, x, {t, 0, 1}, {a}, 
  DependentVariables -> x]
```

The other is to define the black-box function via `SubValues` and set the independent variable `t` as the first argument of the function:

```
f2[t_?NumericQ][a_?NumericQ] := t + a

tstfix2 = ParametricNDSolveValue[{x'[t] == f2[t][a], x[0] == 0}, x, {t, 0, 1}, {a}]
```